# Compare mobile vs. desktop traffic statistics for other websites

Tags: analytics, mobile, traffic, desktop

Is there any way to discover mobile-versus-desktop traffic statistics for ***any*** given website?

I'm currently building a website and it would be incredibly beneficial to me if I could find this information for other websites that offer similar services. I imagine it's currently impossible, but I thought it'd be worth asking.

Answer (score 3):

ANY: No.

You need to have control on the website.

Having said that, tools like semrush, can give you some insight on competition but not quite exact data about mobile vs desktop.

Answer (score 1):

You can get mobile vs desktop stats per sector.  [This article](http://www.smartinsights.com/mobile-marketing/mobile-marketing-analytics/mobile-marketing-statistics/) has nice stats per country and per sector.  If you website is in one of these sectors you can get a rough idea of mobile usage from similar websites:

[image]

[image]